# play framework function testing of json response

Tags: json, playframework, functional-testing

I have I Controller with a method:

```
public static void softwares() {
   List<Software> list = new ArrayList<Software>();
   list.add(new Software("soft 1"));
   list.add(new Software("soft 2"));
   list.add(new Software("soft 3"));
   list.add(new Software("soft 4"));

   renderJSON(list);
}
```

I have a recor in /conf/routes like this:
GET     /my-server/softwares            Application.softwares

I have a function test that try to check that the service responses correctly, and that it return 4 items

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;    
...
@Test
public void softwaresShouldReturnSomething() throws Exception {

 Response response = GET("/myserver-server/softwares");

 assertNotNull(response); // this is OK
 assertIsOk(response); // this is OK

assertContentType("application/json", response); // this is OK
assertCharset("utf-8", response); // this is OK

 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(getContent(response));

 int fieldsPassedCount = doc.children().first().children().size();

 assertTrue(fieldsPassedCount == 4);

}
```

When I debug it the 'doc' variable a have HTML with my values, but I want to have just JSON. What am I doing wrong? and my fieldsPassedCount = 2 here!.

This is how my response look like in 'doc':

```
<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">[{"name":"soft 1"},{"name":"soft 2"},{"name":"soft 3"},{"name":"soft 4"}]</pre></body></html>
```

I tried to change my conf/routes like this (adding the **format:'json'**)

```
GET     /my-server/softwares            Application.softwares(format:'json')
```

So, how would you write that test?

Comment: Can you show the JSON response that you get from the server?

Comment: Assuming you a running on port 9000, you can find the JSON response at http://localhost:9000/my-server/softwares

Comment: <html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">[{"name":"soft 1"},{"name":"soft 2"},{"name":"soft 3"},{"name":"soft 4"}]</pre></body></html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way how to fix it, is doing like this:

1.

```
public class ApplicationTest extends FunctionalTest {
...
String json = getContent(response).toString();
```

So then we have plain json string here.

Then:

2.
Using: org.codehaus.jackson lib

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode firstNode = mapper.readTree(json);
int size = firstNode.size();

assertTrue(size == 4);
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I have amended my answer anyway to reflect the new information that you provided.

Answer (score 2):

#### Edit - testing using objects

I'm glad you found your answer. You could also test your received JSON array by turning the data back to objects - this could be along the lines of:

```
@Test
public void softwaresShouldReturnSomething() throws Exception {

    Http.Response response = GET("/myserver-server/softwares");

    assertIsOk(response);
    assertContentType("application/json", response);
    assertCharset("utf-8", response);

    String content = getContent(response);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type softwareType = new TypeToken<Collection<Softwares>>(){}.getType();
    List<Softwares> softwaresList = gson.fromJson( content, softwareType);

    assertEquals( softwaresList.size(), 4 );
}
```

Comment: even if do not change anything, then the lines: assertContentType("application/json", response);
assertCharset("utf-8", response);
  are ok - they pass with SUCCESS.

Comment: You might be passing valid JSON back, but it might not contain anything. What does the JSON response look like when you point your browser at `/myserver-server/sofwares`?

Comment: in chrome it shows jSON strings like {..., ...} wrapped with html, in firefox it propose to download the file with json string {... , ..} only - but without any html around. So this is valid json it seems. But how to test it them in my method?

Comment: Thanks - I see you have found the answer already, but I thought I would put forward another way using GSON instead - that way you could test the objects in more depth if necessary.

Comment: Great answer. It worked right away for me. I like that you reuse the existing built-in Gson library so I don't have to include a new jar. It's also easy to work with the array as object again, calling methods on them and so on